# If $\textrm{dim}(V)<\infty\Rightarrow \textrm{dim}(U)<\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider $U$ and $V$ two vector spaces over a given field.  $T:U\longrightarrow V$ and $S:V\longrightarrow U$ two linear operators such that $S\circ T=Id_U$. If $\dim(V)<\infty$ how can I prove $\dim(U)<\infty$? Any help will be useful.. Thanks..

Comment: Please, don't write like that. I read it as *if $p\Rightarrow q$ then ...*???

Comment: $T$ is injective under your hypothesis.

Comment: ... and $S$ is onto ...

Answer (score 3):

From your assumptions, $S$ is surjective. That means that the images of a set of generators of $V$ are a set of generators for $U$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can write proof now..

Answer (score 2):

The image of $S$ is finite-dimensional, and the equality $ST=I$ shows that $U$ is the image of $S$.

Comment: Thanks I'll write a proof..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You can for example show that $T$ is injective and use a proof by contradiction.

Let $x \in U$, we have : \begin{eqnarray*}T(x)=0 &\Rightarrow & S(T(x))=0 \\&\Rightarrow& x=0 \end{eqnarray*}

Suppose $U$ has not finite dimension, let $m=\dim V$  there  exists $m+1$ independent vectors $u_1,\cdots,u_{m+1}$ of $U$, then, since $T$ is injective,  $T(u_1),\cdots,T(u_{m+1})$ are independent vectors of $V$; this is a contradiction because $m=\dim V$.

Comment: I just added details. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If DimT < $\infty$ , then $T$ has a representation as an $n \times n$ matrix. If $T$ is invertible, then its inverse is also an $n \times n$ matrix $T^{-1}$ , so that $TT^{-1}=Id$. This shows the inverse is also finite-dimensional.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but there is no concept of dimension of a linear operator so $\textrm{dim}(T)<\infty$ makes no sense..

Comment: Sorry, I meant that an $n\times n$ matrix maps an n-dimensional space to an n-dimensional space, by construction.

Comment: No problem, but you still can't consider such matrix representation  because for doing that you should already know $U$ is also finite dimensional..

Comment: @PtF: I think invertibility of the $n \times n$- matrix $T$ is enough to guarantee the existence of the $n\times n$ matrix $T^{-1}$. But maybe this is not the clearest  argument. Let me think it thru more carefully.

Comment: You are right, for $n\times n$ matrices it suffices one side invertibility..Thanks anyway..